# Analyticity of PDEs

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Do there exist Partial Differential Equations which have been formally proven to have no Analytic Solution?

If yes, what sub branch of mathematics is concerned with proving whether or not PDE’s have analytic solutions? Could someone refer me to any good books or notes on the subject? I am looking for a rigorous text, with emphasis on formal proofs, preferably using the notation of predicate logic, and following an axiomatized approach.

Comment: Should we understand "analytic" as "holomorphic"? and since we a dealing with PDE, it will have to be holomorphic in several variables. In that case I would look for counter examples among the smooth functions that are not analytic, by randomly composing them with some function of several variable and deriving it to see what equation it satisfies... If "analytic" means "possible to express with the usual functions" (products, sum, trigonometric), then I don't think there is a mathematical characterization. One may think of the special functions which are often written as integrals

Comment: A reference (that I did not study and therefore do not really know...) that comes to my mind are the two books on PDEs by Michael Taylor. When I don't know any reference on such a big subject I sometime would go for some kind of "encyclopedia", I'm thinking about the many volumes by Egorov and Shubin

Comment: By analytic I mean has a solution that could be expressed using standard mathematical operators, and not analytic as in holomorphic (that’s not to say that the PDE is not analytic in the holomorphic sense, it may well be.) I often read in texts in Physics and Mathematics that some PDE’s “have no closed form,” or “cannot be expressed in terms of standard mathematical operations .” So I’m looking for a rigorous recount of this.

Comment: I only have basic knowledge of this huge field but I don't think there is a book on this precise question as every book start with (the few) PDEs that do have explicit solutions. Then they discuss existence and unicity of solutions but I don't think they are dealing with whether these are expressible with standard operations... what would be the mathematical characterization of these? (In fact if you allow to express solutions as limits of a sequence of functions, then you'll get to the usual spaces of functions, cf. the Weierstrass like theorems about density of subalgebras of functions...)

Comment: In practice, I think that in books they say no "closed form" in an informal way. Because to  make it rigorous, they should give the exact list of allowed operations (usually the integral is not allowed. We would allow cos, sin, exponential, logarithm, but do we allow artcan?). Then if you want to characterize those space yourself, my only comment is that you have to define a subalgebra of some bigger algebra of functions: indeed you allow +  and x .

Comment: This would be more along the lines of Functional Analysis, but that’s one place worth checking. Thanks for the tip. If you have any ideas on something more general please let me know. Let me rephrase, is there a field of mathematics that combines mathematical logic or “metamathematics” with PDE’s in attempt to develop an encompassing formalism?

Comment: I suspect that I am less experienced in this field than other commenters, but I have a suggestion of where to start reading: [Lewy's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewy%27s_example) of the failure of the analogue of the [Cauchy-Koweleskaya theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kowalevski_theorem) if the analyticity condition is replaced with a smoothness requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but some examples that come to mind for PDE solutions that don't have closed forms are:
- Fourier Series solutions on a bounded domain, where the solution is often an infinite sum
- Heat equation on unbounded domains, where the solution is given as an integral [see here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/pde/heat/Heat-Green.pdf)
- Poisson equation on a bounded domain, where the solution is given by two integrals [see eqn 4.6](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/greensfcns.pdf)

Comment: Not sure where to find examples of proof to equations that there is definitely no analytic solution though.

Comment: Again, it seems to me that there is an arbitrariness in the notion of "closed form". Why is exponential an allowed function? It is itself define as a solution of an ODE. It is itself written as an infinite sum. I'm not sure logic and PDE are trying to answer the same questions and therefore I don't think there is any book trying to unify both subjects.

Comment: In fact we should still mention the following [Liouville thm (fr)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Liouville_(alg%C3%A8bre_diff%C3%A9rentielle)#Relation_avec_la_th%C3%A9orie_de_Galois_diff%C3%A9rentielle_et_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ralisations) and the [Three-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem)